# Equivalent of URL parsing PCRE regex for .NET

Tags: regex

There's a PCRE regex for extracting URLs posted here: http://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls

```
\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))
```

What would need to be changed to make it compatible with regex in .NET?

Comment: Try parsing the regex by hand to understand how it works. When you do, converting each syntax element to the .NET equivalent should be straightforward.

Comment: You're right, Anon. Why would we need to ask questions on Stack Overflow when we could do it ourselves. Silly me. Time to cancel my account. :-)

Comment: If the question is "help my copy-paste this code that I don't quite understand", the correct answer is to help them understand it, not provide some more code that they don't understand but that you think does maybe something close to what they want.

Comment: I could figure it out, but I am choosing to spend my time elsewhere. Plus I think this could help other people in the future.

Comment: Also, I think you'll find yourself enjoying SO more if you just take questions at face value and don't make assumptions about the asker, especially those that have been around a long time. The way this question is posted is 100% intentional. And I got my answer in < 10 minutes so I'd call this a success.

Comment: Just happened to have Twitter open when I saw this and happened to be working with Regexbuddy. Did I ever mention Regexbuddy is **awesome**?

Comment: You're suggesting that questions like "how do I parse HTML with regular expressions" should just be answered, rather than the asker informed that it's a bad idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at in Regexbuddy now. So far, the only issue is the [:punct:] - doesn't look like .NET supports POSIX character classes.

EDIT - double clicking on the offender gave me this:

```
\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^\p{P}\s]|/)))
```

[image]